# Google Drive API for iOS app instruction and redirect_uri_mismatch error message

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I tried to follow Google's [instructions](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios). But on the Google Cloud Console, there is no Registered apps menu.  Nor I could find a way to exam what is the current redirect_uri for the app.

In my test iOS app, I got this error after signed in.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: urn:ietf:wq:oauth:2.0:oob did not match a registered redirect URI

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a two step process.

First you create a **project**, then you create one or more **clients** (aka **apps**). It is at the client/app level that you will see a field for the redirect URLs. Make sure that these exactly (character by character) match the redirect URL you are specifying in your OAuth call.

I believe that for an iOS app, the Cloud Console will prefill the redirect URLs on your behalf, and should of course be "urn:ietf:wq:oauth:2.0:oob"

Comment: The current instructions from Google does not seem to match their current UI on the site.  I could not find anything about redirect url.  I deleted the project and re-recreated new one with new client and still got the same error.

Comment: The instructions probably refer to the older version API Console, rather than the new Cloud Console. If you look at the bottom, there is a grey link to 'return to the original console"